# Make Gmail refresh every 30 minutes?

Tags: gmail

30 minutes is just one example. Basically, is there a way to make the web version of Gmail sync/refresh just every X minutes and not instantly as it seems to be the default?

I find it annoying to see new emails flowing in at any given time while responding to other emails.

Answer (score 0):

Close the browser tab, and it won't tell you when you have email. Of course that means you have to remember to open it again.

Otherwise there is no way to tell gmail to check less often.

Comment: Not really solving my problem. I don't want new emails coming in while responding to older emails.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your Gmail account on any other email client app (Eg. Outlook) and set the sync frequency time.
Use the same email client for sending emails peacefully.

[image: change sync settings in outlook windows]

Comment: It would be nice if whoever anonymously downvoted this answer also supplied a comment indicating what is wrong with it.